# How to get the dependencies of a NuGet package from private NuGet feed?

Tags: c#, nuget

I have tried this for load a package using [NuGet.Core](http://blog.nuget.org/20130520/Play-with-packages.html). How shall I proceed further on this? I need to get the list of dependency packages of the package in a list from public/private feed using C#.

```
string packageID = "EntityFramework";
IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2");
var package = repo.FindPackage(packageID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found solution. `package.DependencySets` gives the dependency sets.